# Partition names in /media change frequently, how to force stable name?

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, partitioning, media

After an unexpected shutdown (due to a power outage), partition names in `/media` folder has changed, in fact it happened twice before the shutdown , `/media` included only one sub-folder named `432da03f-95cc-4b58-9bd5-b8f091a079f6` after two unexpected shutdowns two additional subfolders appeared, `432da03f-95cc-4b58-9bd5-b8f091a079f61` and `432da03f-95cc-4b58-9bd5-b8f091a079f62`, each of them was added after one shutdown as a new name of the partitions. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

How can I force the system to use stable names of that partition?

Answer (score 0):

They are stable names, they're just not cool with humans being all hexadecimal. You can write a script to create soft links called disk-01, disk-02 etc

Comment: You do not need a script, just assign labels to all partitions. I use gparted when creating partitions or Disks when editing them. Use little star type icon for more actions. With gpt there are not two places to label and I am not sure which is used for mounting. One is edit file system label which is the one I think is used, and the other is edit partition & then name.